# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''')

Tags: php, syntax-error

Am pretty new to PHP and stuch with this problem.

Am trying to insert some info from a dropdown menu into a database but keep getting this error. Please help if you can.

The php code is:

```
<select name="group_ID">
    <?php
    $pos_query ="SELECT  groupName, group_ID FROM 'operations' JOIN members WHERE operations.group_ID = members.group_ID";
    $pos_results = $db->query($pos_query);

    for ( $i=0; $i < $pos_results->num_rows ; $i++ )
    {
        $pos_row = $pos_results->fetch_assoc();
        echo'<option value"'.$pos_row['group_ID'].'">';
        echo $pos_row['groupName'].'</option>';
    }

    ?></select></td>
```

I have a table called operations and trying to join it to another table called members and insert the data into the members table.
The error is: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''') SELECT 'Church Elders' FROM operations JOIN members ON ope' at line 1.

Sorry guys I posted the wrong code. 
The actual code is:

$query = "INSERT INTO members(email, name, gender, dob, profile, password,) 
            SELECT $group_ID 
            FROM operations
            JOIN members
            WHERE operations.group_ID = '$group_ID'" ;

```
$result = $db->query($query);
```

Am trying to insert email, name, gender... group_ID into the members table and getting the group_ID from the operations table and gets the following error message:

Error Inserting Details. Error Message:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') SELECT Church Elders FROM operations JOIN members WHERE oper' at line 1.

Please help!!!!

Comment: We need the value of `$pos_query`.

Comment: you have an error in sql command. not above.

Comment: Please post the error.

Comment: Remove the quotes around `operations`?

Comment: The error is: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''') SELECT 'Church Elders' FROM operations JOIN members ON ope' at line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use single quote with table name('operations') & specify table name with row like groupName.operations, group_ID.operations.

Comment: Tried that but no luck.

Comment: I have tested it using dummy data like "SELECT  table1.num1 FROM table1 JOIN table2 WHERE table1.id = table2.id" & found ok, can you specify new error message?

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant to use backticks in your SQL query, not single-quotes. Also, you probably meant the `ON` statement, rather than `WHERE`. `WHERE` is for filtering, while `ON` tells the `JOIN` statement which columns to join on.

```
SELECT `groupName`, `group_ID` FROM `operations` JOIN `members` ON `operations`.`group_ID` = `members`.`group_ID`
```

Comment: I did change the WHERE to ON and used the backticks but still getting the error message. Getting frustrating!!!!

Comment: Which error? The one in the title, or the one in your latest comment to the OP? The error in your OP comment looks like you're trying to do multiple queries in one `query()` call, which isn't possible with that function, regardless of the lack of semicolon.